# Flickr like animation on Android

Tags: java, android, animation, android-viewpager, flickr

I am struggling to make animations like on Flickr app on android.
I already know how to switch from a fragment to another fragment in a view pager.
Due I have no clue how to do these kind of animations.

[image]

Comment: truthfully this is probably not a `Viewpager` and probably is a Custom `Horizontal Scrollview` made to look like a view pager

Comment: These are gif files used with parallax effect, which together with the position value are used to create the effect

Comment: https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4#.e2jb98if4